# Microsoft excel: Queries and connections - option to update data manually is greyed out

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, editing, links, query

For my link to other excel workbook table:

[image]

For some reason, the **update: manual** option is greyed out for this query link in excel Data --> edit links.

I don't want the data to update automatically however. For all clarity, the edit links button is NOT greyed out, I saw that many people encountered that problem, but I don't.

How can I solve this?

[image]